# Heroku Postgres database randomly crashing, "error: terminating connection due to administrator command"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

Every once in a while Postgres will just error out (error message at the bottom). I can't force it to crash ever so I can't reproduce it to find the source of the error. I'm also on the free tier so there are no Postgres logs.

I'm running a Slack app using Bolt.js on a Heroku dyno.

In app.js I connect to the DB

```
const pg_client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});
pg_client.connect();
```

Then I have a generic query function that takes in the client, the query, and the values

```
//Generic query function
    let res;
    try {
      await pg_client.query("BEGIN");
      try {
        res = await pg_client.query(q, v);
        await pg_client.query("COMMIT");
      } catch (err) {
        await pg_client.query("ROLLBACK");
        throw err;
      }
    } finally {
      //client.release()
    }
    return res;
}

module.exports = { query };
```

**I'm just realizing is my `throw err;` line above causing Postgres to crash if a query fails? Should I just log that error instead?**

Do I need to be releasing my client any restarting it every query? Do I need to set up pooling or something? Heroku dynos restart every 24 hours so it's not like my connection is open for weeks.

Any help that points me in the right direction would be amazing. Thank you!

The error message is

```
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932529+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:292
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932548+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932549+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932549+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932552+00:00 app[web.1]: error: terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932554+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932554+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932555+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932556+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932556+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932557+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932557+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932558+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932558+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932559+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932559+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorEvent (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:319:10)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932559+00:00 app[web.1]: at Client._handleErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:330:12)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932560+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932560+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:115:12
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932561+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932561+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932562+00:00 app[web.1]: [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932562+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932563+00:00 app[web.1]: length: 116,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932563+00:00 app[web.1]: severity: 'FATAL',
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932564+00:00 app[web.1]: code: '57P01',
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932564+00:00 app[web.1]: detail: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932565+00:00 app[web.1]: hint: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932565+00:00 app[web.1]: position: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932566+00:00 app[web.1]: internalPosition: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932566+00:00 app[web.1]: internalQuery: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932566+00:00 app[web.1]: where: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932567+00:00 app[web.1]: schema: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932567+00:00 app[web.1]: table: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932567+00:00 app[web.1]: column: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932568+00:00 app[web.1]: dataType: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932568+00:00 app[web.1]: constraint: undefined,
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932569+00:00 app[web.1]: file: 'postgres.c',
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932569+00:00 app[web.1]: line: '3023',
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932570+00:00 app[web.1]: routine: 'ProcessInterrupts'
2021-03-15T21:04:15.932570+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-15T21:04:16.359776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-15T21:04:16.449742+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-03-15T21:04:16.501439+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-15T21:04:20.383409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-03-15T21:04:23.522205+00:00 app[web.1]: ⚡️ Bolt app is running!
2021-03-15T21:04:24.872264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-15T21:06:30.856589+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.152.19.239:5432
2021-03-15T21:06:30.856610+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
2021-03-15T21:06:30.856611+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-03-15T21:06:30.857096+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that somebody sent the signal `SIGTERM` to the database process.

- Perhaps a rogue piece of your code is killing sessions by calling the `pg_terminate_backend` function.
- The alternative is that the database is shut down in the default fast mode.

Consult the database log to figure out which of the two things happened.

Comment: Thanks for your input! For sure my code isn't calling `pg_terminate_backend`


How/why would the DB shut down in the default fast mode?


Unfortunately, I'm on the free Postgres tier on Heroku so there are no logs : /

Comment: I don't know when Heroku chooses to shut down its databases. If you have no access to the log, you are pretty lost. Perhaps ask your service provider. I can only tell you what can cause this message.

Comment: The first line of the error log is `even.tsjs:292 throw er; //unhandled 'error' event`. So it seems like an uncaught error crashed the whole thing. But then the Postgres error says `terminating connection due to admin.` Are those two things conflicting?

Comment: That is not the PostgreSQL log. If there is a database crash, you get a different error message.